# MYSQL Order by Day Buried in String

Tags: mysql

I've got a bunch of rows with a field called "title" who's data looks like this:

```
Friday  8:00AM - Hunter Arena 2
Wednesday  7:30AM - West Grass Field
Thursday  8:00AM - Hunter Arena 1
Saturday  8:00AM - Hunter Arena 1
Wednesday  8:00AM - Hunter Arena 2
```

I'm looking to order by the day in the week.  (Which I assume would involve parsing the string and then doing some sort of date sort) Is this possible with a MYSQL query?

Thanks in advance
-J

Comment: You could use regular expressions to extract the date and then sort by it but that probably would be an overkill especially if you have many records. Any reason for not having separate columns?

Comment: Shouldn't ordering by the string already sort it by the week day?

Comment: @darin,  I'm lazy.  The records I get are from a site with all that info in the same table row, when I originally wrote the program I didn't think to extract the day into another column, and I'm hoping I can avoid going back in and adding that column.  @Pekka, it groups the days, but not in the order of the week.

Comment: @Jascha I'm not seeing any week number in the data you show?

Comment: @Jascha it's exactly because you are lazy that you should have done this. Because now the amount of work that you will need to do in order to sort those records would be important compared to an additional column in your `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: @Darin, lazy pays double....  @pekka.  I mean in order of the week as in Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday (instead of just alphabetical)

Comment: @Darin, believe me, I wish I had.

Comment: @Jascha ah, of course. My bad. Then you'll have to use a regex or REPLACE instruction during sorting - but that is terribly slow. Is there no option to add another column at all?

Comment: @pekka, there is.  That's just what I'm trying to avoid.  I was hoping there was a query command like (ORDERY BY `title` SUBSTRING(`title`,' ') DAY OF WEEK FOR YOU LAZY CODERS)

Comment: That would indeed be possible - you'd have to find the first occurrence of a space, LTRIM everything before it, compare it and return a numeric value. But it's slow (because it will have to be run on every record to create a sorting order) and probably 10 lines long :) A simple cascading `REPLACE(column, "Monday", "1")` spanning across all weekdays is too risky because the weekday *could* be in the location name. It's really better to add that column.

Comment: @pekka, in case you're curious I did end up adding the column.  I had to cycle through old data to populate the field, but overall it functions better.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to creating a holding table (temp, permanent, your choice!) of some kind of your weekdays and their sort weight.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE WkDayWeight (weekday varchar(100), orderWeight int); 
INSERT INTO WkDayWeight  (weekday, orderWeight)
   SELECT           'Monday',1
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Tuesday',2 
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Wednesday',3
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Thursday',4
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Friday',5
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Saturday',6
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Sunday',7
```

Then you could extract the first word from your column (i.e. find the day of week), and JOIN the holding/reference table of weekday sort weights.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    MyTable AS m 
INNER JOIN WkDayWeight   AS d 
  ON d.weekday = SUBSTRING_INDEX(m.MyColumn,' ',1) 
ORDER BY d.orderWeight
```

It's much more preferable to actually have a `datetime` column to be able to naturally sort by.

*Another alternative*: you could achieve this another way by creating a user-defined function who could do the same. You could then, with dubious performance, call the UDF in your `ORDER BY`. The function would find/refer to the weight of the weekday.

```
  ORDER BY MyWeekdaySortingFunction(m.MyColumn)
```

Answer (score 2):

Put an inline case/when clause for the order by...

```
select 
      yt.YourDataColumns
   from 
      YourTable yt
   order by 
      case when "Sunday" = left( yt.Title, 6 ) then 1
           when "Monday" = left( yt,Title, 6 ) then 2
           when "Tuesday" = left( yt,Title, 7 ) then 3
           when "Wednesday" = left( yt,Title, 9 ) then 4
           when "Thursday" = left( yt,Title, 8 ) then 5
           when "Friday" = left( yt,Title, 6 ) then 6
           else 7
      end
```

Comment: +1. This is simpler than my answer. If it's a one-off, then I'd go with this solution. Otherwise, if 2+ snippet of code needs the functionality, I'd put it into a lookup table or UDF.